# Visual Studio 2010 + CUDA 4: Unrecognized token error when attempting to allocate memory using NPP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cuda

I have the following source file (CUDA_Integral_Image.cu) for a class of the same name:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "npp.h"
#include "CUDA_Integral_Image.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

...

// allocated device source image
int step = width;
Npp8u* pSI = nppiMalloc_8u_C1(width, height, &step);
// copy test image up to device
cudaMemcpy2D(pSI, width, pHI, width, width, height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
// allocate device result images
Npp32s* pDi = nppiMalloc_32s_C1(width,height,width*sizeof(int)); // LINE 30
```

Attempting to compile this code results in:

```
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(30): error : unrecognized token
1>  
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(30): error : expected an identifier
1>  
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(30): error : unrecognized token
1>  
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(30): error : expected an expression
```

There are no other header files included in CUDA_Integral_Image.h. All the NPP dependencies (.h and lib) seem to be added without problems. Furthermore, Npp8u* and nppiMalloc_8u_C1 are recognized just fine. I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this error.

..if I change the code to:

```
Npp32s* pDi; // LINE 30
pDi = nppiMalloc_32s_C1(width,height,width*sizeof(int));
```

I get the errors:

```
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(30): error : unrecognized token
1>  
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(30): error : expected an identifier
1>  
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(31): error : identifier "pDi" is undefined
1>  
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(31): error : unrecognized token
1>  
.../CUDA_Integral_Image.cu(31): error : expected an expression
```

No idea what could be causing this, would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to nppiMalloc_32s_C1 is incorrect. It should always be a pointer to an integer variable. The routine internally calculates the correct size for the allocation (include alignment) and returns the size to the caller.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you very much. Makes a lot more sense now. First time using this and nowhere in the documentation does it actually say that it calculates the line step for you. :/

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what is a good place to learn to use NPP? I haven't been able to find anything at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know of one.

Comment: Just in case you're interested, in the end the only problem was that the step size was not a pointer, but you still have to specify a value for the step size. Passing an empty pointer causes the program to crash.